# How to reduce a list to a single value

Tags: elixir

I'm currently reading the Programming Elixir 1.6 Book, and on page 88 there's a challenge to create a function (mapsum) that accepts a list, and a function.

This mapsum function is supposed to take the function provided as a parameter, iterate over every element in the list due to recursion, after effecting every number in the list, all the results are to be added.

For example:

> `[1, 2, 3], &(&1 * &1)` - Params passed to mapsum.

Expected Outcome:

```elixir
[1, 4, 9] # Answer after each number in map has been effected by function.
[14] # Final answer after the values are added.
```

Right now I'm able to get the `[1, 4, 9]` answer to print.
After that, I tried adding the code that would add the values together.

In attempting to do so my elixir console throws an error saying I'm passing an empty list as the first argument to the function [].  Here's what I'm doing right now to get the [1, 4, 9] answer:

```elixir
def mapsum([], _fun), do: []

def mapsum([head | tail], func) do
    [func.(head) | mapsum(tail, func)]
end
```

So as you can see it accepts a list and function just like the challenge said.  To try to get the addition of the values here's what I tried that DID NOT WORK:

```elixir
def mapsum([], _fun, val), do: []

def mapsum([head | tail], func, val \\ 0) do
    [func.(head) + val | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
end
```

In my mind this makes perfect sense. I feel as though I'm missing an underlying thing that elixir is doing.

Here's what I expect to happen with what I've typed:  mapsum gets passed a list [1, 2, 3] and a function `&(&1 * &1)`, val can be specified as 0, or left alone as it has a default value of 0. Mapsum then runs the anon func on the head (first value) of the passed in list.  Then that returned result is added to val, after that we then call mapsum on the tail, (or remainder values), with the same function, and the updated val.

This should work until an empty list is passed and is caught by the first function.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  I've been having major troubles writing what seems to be the simplest of functions in elixir.  An answer on the above problem with a detailed explanation of what I'm missing would be incredibly helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my copy of `Programming Elixir 1.6`, the exercise is on `p. 77` (not p. 88).

```
Expected Outcome:

`[1, 4, 9]` - Answer after each number in map has been effected by function.

`[14]` - Final answer after the values are added.
```

After the exercise description, my book gives this example:

```
iex> MyList.mapsum [1, 2, 3], &(&1 * &1)
14
```

The expected outcome is `14`, and there is no intermediate result like `[1, 4, 9]` expected.

> ```
> def mapsum([], _fun, val), do: []
> def mapsum([head | tail], func, val \\ 0) do
>     [func.(head) + val | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
> end
> ```
>
> In my mind this makes perfect sense. I feel as though I'm missing an
>   underlying thing that elixir is doing...***mapsum then runs the anon func
>   on the head (first value) of the passed in list. Then that returned
>   result is added to val,***

Well, the returned value of the function is added to the ***value*** of the `val` variable, but that sum is never assigned to the `val` variable.  Here's an example in iex:

```
iex(5)> val = 0
0

iex(6)> val + 1
1

iex(7)> val
0
```

To add something to the `val` variable, you would have to write:

```
iex(8)> val = val + 1
1
```

Instead, the expression you wrote was:

```
[func.(head) + val | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
```

The first time your `mapsum` function executes, `val=0` and `func.(head)` returns `1`, so elixir substitutes those values into your expression giving you:

```
[1 + 0 | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
```

or:

```
[1 | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
```

Next, elixir substitutes in the values for `tail`, `func`, and `val`, giving you:

```
[1 | mapsum([2, 4], &(&1 * &1), 0)]
```

There ***is*** a way to assign a new value to a variable without explicitly writing `=` in your code.  Suppose you have this def:

```
def repeat(_, 0), do: :ok

def repeat(greeting, times) do
  IO.puts greeting
  repeat(greeting, times-1)
end
```

and you call the function like this:

```
repeat("hello", 4)
```

When `repeat()` executes, elixir will need to evaluate the following expression in the body of the function:

```
repeat(greeting, times-1)
```

The first time `repeat()` executes, `greeting="hello"` and `times=4`, so elixir first substitutes the values for those variables into the expression, like this:

```
repeat("hello", 4-1)
```

which gives you:

```
repeat("hello", 3)
```

Next, the arguments in that function call get matched to the function parameter variables like this:

```
        repeat("hello",    3 )     #<===function call
                  |        |
 greeting="hello" |        | times=3
                  V        V
    def repeat(greeting, times) do  #<====function definition
```

In other words, calling a function results in implicit assignment of the arguments to the function parameter variables.  Then, inside the body of the function you can use the names `greeting` and `times` to retrieve their respective values.

But, in your expression:

```
[func.(head) + val | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
```

the portion:

```
func.(head) + val
```

is not an argument to a function call, so the sum does not get assigned to any parameter variable.

**Spoiler: my solution follows**
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_

```
  def mapsum([head|tail], func) do
      func.(head) + mapsum(tail, func) 
  end

  def mapsum([], _func), do: 0
```

That solution uses the same logic as the example on `p. 73`, which finds the length of a list:

```
def len([head|tail]) do
  1 + len(tail)
end
```

...with the terminating case being:

```
def len([]), do: 0
```

Contrary to my `mapsum()` solution above, I generally find it easier to devise a recursive solution by using what's called an *accumulator*, which is a basic recursion trick.  The book hasn't used an accumulator in an example yet, but here's a simple `sum_list()` example that uses an accumulator:

```
  def sum_list(list), do: sum_list(list, 0)

  def sum_list([], acc), do: acc
  def sum_list([head|tail], acc) do
    sum_list(tail, acc+head)
  end
```

You convert the `sum_list(list)` function call into a function call with two arguments, which is done in this line:

```
def sum_list(list), do: sum_list(list, 0)
```

The second argument, `0`, is what's known as the accumulator: it will accumulate the result that you are interested in returning at the end of the recursion.  Note that in elixir, the functions `sum_list/1` and `sum_list/2` are completely different functions, and they have nothing to do with each other.  If it makes it easier to understand, you can use a different name for the two argument function, e.g.:

```
def sum_list(list), do: my_helper(list, 0)
```

If `list` is not empty, the two argument function call will match this function clause:

```
  def sum_list([head|tail], acc) do
```

and `0` will get assigned to the `acc` parameter variable.  Then, you can add values to acc in the body of the `sum_list/2` definition:

```
def sum_list([head|tail], acc) do
  new_acc = acc + head  #<==== HERE
  sum_list(tail, new_acc)  
end
```

...and use the new value for the accumulator in the recursive function call.  Note that the last code snippet can be simplified like this:

```
def sum_list([head|tail], acc) do
  sum_list(tail, acc+head)  
end
```

Then, when the tail of the list is an empty list, ending the recursion, you return the accumulator:

```
def sum_list([], acc), do: acc
```

> I've been having major troubles writing what seems to be the simplest
>   of functions in elixir.

Keep struggling and trying.  When I started erlang, I sometimes spent a week trying to solve a simple recursion problem.  In your attempts with this exercise, it looks to me like you almost invented the accumulator concept, so good on you.  Even if you don't figure out a solution, if you struggle for a while then look at a solution, usually a light bulb will go off. Using recursion will get easier.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much.  This really helped.  My first language was JavaScript so I'm still trying to get out of the mindset of an object oriented language.  I hadn't thought or heard of an accumulator before, but the idea totally makes sense.  I appreciate your time and help tremendously.

Comment: @JoeyBrown, You are welcome!  If you want more resources for learning recursion, I can recommend [Programming Erlang](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Erlang-Concurrent-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/193778553X)

Answer (score 1):

```
def mapsum(list, fun, val \\ 0)
def mapsum([], _fun, val), do: val
def mapsum([head | tail], fun, val), do: mapsum(tail, fun, val + fun.(head))
```

Lets go over this line by line.

Our first definition just states that the third argument has a default value of `0`. Nothing more.

Our second definition says that if we have an empty list, it will return the current `val`. This may be `0` if we passed in an empty list (`mapsum([], &(&1 * &1))`), or it could be the accumulated value if passing in a non-empty list (`mapsum([1,2,3], &(&1 * &1))`).

Our third definition is where the main logic actually is. It uses pattern matching to separate out the `head` and the `tail` of the list. It then calls our function recursively using the `tail` as the new first argument, keeping the `fun` as is, and changing the `val` so that it takes the current `val` and adds the result of `fun` applied to `head`.

Lets see how this actually gets expanded out.

```
mapsum([1,2,3], &(&1 * &1))

mapsum([2,3], &(&1 * &1), 0 + fun.(1)
mapsum([2,3], &(&1 * &1), 1)

mapsum([3], &(&1 * &1), 1 + fun.(2)
mapsum([3], &(&1 * &1), 5)

mapsum([], &(&1 * &1), 5 + fun.(3)
mapsum([], &(&1 * &1), 14)

14
```

This is different from your approach because here I am summing as I go, where your solution did the `map` part (it created a new list with `fun` applied to each element), but you were unable to apply the actual `sum` part on the new list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the challenge is to implement this not using the Enum module. I would still start by implementing this using the Enum module and then reimplement the functions used in Enum.

```
defmodule MyList 
  do def mapsum(list, f) do 
    Enum.map(list, f) |> Enum.sum 
  end 
end
```

The next step would be to reimplement map and sum

```
defmodule MyList do
  def mapsum(list, f) do
    map(list, f) |> sum
  end

  defp sum([head | tail]) do
    head + sum(tail)
  end
  defp sum([]) do
    0
  end

  defp map([head | tail], f) do
    [f.(head)|map(tail, f)]
  end
  defp map([], _f) do
    []
  end

end
```

Both sum and map can be implemented using reduce, that could be a follow-up exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

What this is doing:

```elixir
def mapsum([head | tail], func, val \\ 0) do
    [func.(head) + val | mapsum(tail, func, val)]
end
```

Is running `func` over each element, and adding `0` (or `val`) to it - but `val` stays constant and is never updated, and the function still returns a list.

I suggest you rename `val` to `acc` because it is supposed to hold the accumulated value. Then you can write it like this:

```elixir
def mapsum([], _fun, acc), do: acc

def mapsum([head | tail], func, acc \\ 0) do
  mapsum(tail, func, acc + func.(head))
end
```

This does two things:

1. When the list is empty, print the `acc`umulated value.
2. When the list is not empty, recurse with the tail, and add the head to the accumulated value.